# What does the corner-asterisk mean in the Extensions sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the Extensions Sidebar, some of my installed extensions are marked in their upper-left corner with an asterisk.  No amount of searching has enlightened me as to what this means.

[Screenshot of Extensions Sidebar showing some entries marked with an asterisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMFHA.png)

### Possibilities I've eliminated

#### Recommended?

After all, *all* the extensions in the `RECOMMENDED` section have this asterisk.

However, aside from the silliness of recommending an extension I already have installed, it turns out that only *some* of these marked extensions carry the byline *"This extension is recommended based on..."* when I open them.

#### In need of update?

If this is the case, I cannot locate any means of updating any of these extensions individually.  I assume my extensions auto-update.

#### Highly rated?

No, my marked extensions do not consistently have more stars or more downloads than my unmarked extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think those are recommended extensions despite what you say in your question.  Why?  Because if you click the Gear icon and select `Ignore Recommendation` the asterisk goes away.  And that extension will no longer appear in your `@recommnded` workspace filter.

Comment: Interesting.  I can confirm that all marked, and only marked, extensions have the "Ignore Recommendation" option.  However, _none_ of these appear in the `@recommended` filter, ignored or not.

Comment: Selecting "Ignore Recommendation" removes the corner-asterisk, so I'd say that's pretty definitive.

Comment: So, this leaves me wondering, what is the _expected_ response to this call-to-action? Other than picking it for "Ignore"?